# implementing SerialPortEventListener - java

Tags: java, javax.comm

I am trying to implement SerialPortEventListener but failed. My code is

```
public class Communicator implements SerialPortEventListener{
```

My netbeans 7.1 shows `mateorssms.Communicator` is not abstract and does not override abstract method `serialEvent(javax.comm.SerialPortEvent)` in `javax.comm.SerialPortEventListener`. I've successfully imported `javax.comm.*;`. What is wrong with me?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Communicator` class needs a to implement a method

```
@Override
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent ev) {
  // TODO do something with ev
}
```

That's all. Add this method stub to your class and the error is gone. Then add some functionality to that method.